# Weak convergence (in $H_0^1$) in the proof of the bounded inverse theorem in Evans's PDE book

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

The following is the bounded inverse theorem for the elliptic equations in Evans's *Partial Differential Equations* (Chapter 6):

> [image]

Here $\Sigma$ is the (real) spectrum of the elliptic operator $L$, where
[image]
[image]

The proof essential uses weak convergence in $H_0^1(U)$:

> [image]

Here are my **questions**:

- How is (30) used in passing the limit (in subsequence) in the first read box? Here "in the weak sense" means for every $v\in H_0^1(U)$, 
  $$
  \int_U\sum a^{ij}\cdot(u_k)_{x_i}v_{x_j}+\sum b^i\cdot(u_k)_{x_i}v+cu_kv=\lambda (u_k,v)+(f_k,v)
  $$ 
  where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the $L^2$ inner product. Convergence of the term $(f_k,v)$ term is trivial by Cauchy-Schwartz. How to give the convergence in other terms? Relabeling the subsequence as $u_k$, weak convergence in $H_0^1(U)$ means for each $v\in H_0^1(U)$:
  $$
  (\nabla u_k,\nabla v)+(u_k,v)\to(\nabla u,\nabla v)+(u,v).
  $$
- Why is $L^2$ convergence in (30) needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Evans is really doing here is using the fact that $\nabla u_k$ converges weakly in $L^2$.  The assumptions on $A$ guarantee that $A \nabla v \in L^2$ whenever $v \in H^1$, and so 
$$
\int A \nabla u_k \cdot \nabla v = \int \nabla u_k \cdot A \nabla v \to \int \nabla u \cdot A \nabla v = \int A \nabla u \cdot \nabla v.
$$
Similarly, 
$$
\int b \cdot \nabla u_k v \to \int b \cdot \nabla u v
$$
due to the fact that $b v \in L^2$ whenever $v \in H^1$.

The strong convergence $u_k \to u$ in $L^2$ is overkill for the convergence in the weak solution since weak convergence is enough to get 
$$
\int \lambda u_k v \to \int \lambda u v, 
$$
but he has the strong convergence, so he uses it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask how you get weak convergence of $\nabla u_k$ in $L^2$?

Comment: Sure!  It's the same way you get weak convergence in $H^1$: we have that $\nabla u_k$ is uniformly bounded in $L^2$, so by weak compactness in $L^2$ we have that $\nabla u_k \rightharpoonup X$ weakly as $k \to \infty$.  The weak convergence in $H^1$ guarantees that in fact $X = \nabla u$.

Comment: @Jack and Glitch, I can be wrong but it seems that the $L^2$-convergence is not an overkill in the proof. Of course, as pointed out in the post, it is not needed to pass the limit. However, there is other purpose for its use. See my post.

Answer (score 2):

### First Question

You know that
$$u_k\rightharpoonup u\text{ in } H_0^1(U).$$
Using this you want to pass to the limit in
$$\int_U\sum a^{ij}\cdot(u_k)_{x_i}v_{x_j}+\sum b^i\cdot(u_k)_{x_i}v+cu_kv\;dx=\lambda (u_k,v)+(f_k,v)$$
to obtain
$$\int_U\sum a^{ij} u_{x_i}v_{x_j}+\sum b^i u_{x_i}v+cuv\;dx=\lambda (u,v)+(f,v).\tag{1}$$

You know how to pass the limit in the last term. So, let us consider the other terms.

Note that, for each fixed $i$ and $j$, the maps
\begin{align}
H_0^1 (U)\ni w &\mapsto a^{ij} w_{x_i}\in L^2(U)\\
H_0^1 (U)\ni w &\mapsto b^{i} w_{x_i}\in L^2(U)\\
H_0^1 (U)\ni w &\mapsto cw\in L^2(U)\\
H_0^1 (U)\ni w &\mapsto \lambda w\in L^2(U)
\end{align}
are linear and continuous and thus they [preserve weak convergence](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~bwick6/teaching/math6338/math6338_hw4.pdf). So, 
\begin{align}a^{ij} (u_k)_{x_i}&\rightharpoonup a^{ij}u_{x_i} \text{ in } L^2(U)\\
b^{i} (u_k)_{x_i}&\rightharpoonup b^iu_{x_i}\text{ in }L^2(U)\\
cu_k&\rightharpoonup cu\text{ in } L^2(U)\\
\lambda u_k&\rightharpoonup\lambda u\text{ in } L^2(U)\end{align}
for each $i$ and each $j$, which imply

\begin{align}
\int_U\sum a^{ij}\cdot(u_k)_{x_i}v_{x_j}=\sum \int_Ua^{ij}(u_k)_{x_i}v_{x_j}&\longrightarrow \sum \int_Ua^{ij}u_{x_i}v_{x_j}=\int_U\sum a^{ij}u_{x_i}v_{x_j}\\
\int_U\sum b^{i}\cdot(u_k)_{x_i}v=\sum \int_Ub^{i}(u_k)_{x_i}v&\longrightarrow \sum \int_Ub^{i}u_{x_i}v=\int_U\sum b^{i}u_{x_i}v\\
\int_Ucu_kv&\longrightarrow\int_Ucuv\\
\lambda(u_k,v)=\int_U\lambda u_kv&\longrightarrow\int_U\lambda uv=\lambda(u,v)
\end{align}
Adding  you get $(1)$.

### Second Question

We know that $\|u_k\|_{L^2}=1$ for all $k$. Due to the strong convergence
$$u_{k_j}\longrightarrow u\text{ in } L^2(U)$$
we conclude that $\|u\|_{L^2}=1$ (which is used to get the contradiction).